# how to read php array into variable

Tags: php

I'm using ajax to post my json data ( to ci controller )
and then `json_decode` to read my data.

this data from table

```
Array
(
    [Detail] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [row0] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [row1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [cell0] => 04019
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [cell1] => 
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [cell2] => 2.00
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [cell3] => 
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [cell4] => 4530000
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [cell5] => 
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [cell6] => 
                                )

                        )

                )


        )

)
```

I want to read data and update the database using the ci model

```
    $data = array(
     'Customer'  => $this->input->post('Customer'),
     'Total' => $this->input->post('Total'),
     'Detail' => $this->input->post('Detail')
    );

    $json = json_decode($data['Detail'],true);

    $Sql ="";
    $row=0;
    foreach ($json as $doc)
    {
        if ($row !=0)
        {
         $Sql .= ' Insert Detail' + $doc[0]->cell0 . ' ' . $doc[2]->cell2  . ' ' . $doc[4]->cell4;
        }
         $row++;
    }

print_r($Sql);
```

but it's not working,

How to read the data array and save it to the `Sql` var. Thanks

Comment: "but doesn't work,"  _In what way_ does it not work?  What _does_ happen?  Are you getting errors?  If so, what are the exact error messages?  If not, how does the result differ from the expected result?  What debugging have you already done?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please have a look at the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. It says it's better to explain the error you get instead of saying "it doesn't work". It helps people to answer your question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that query? Supposing you are using mysql check this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Codeigniter works.

You should respect MVC, having something like this:

Controller:

```
$details = json_decode($data['Detail'],true);

$this->load->model('my_model');

foreach($details as $detail)
{
    $this->my_model->add_detail($detail);
}
```

Model:

```
function add_detail($detail)
{
    $this->db->insert('table_name', $detail);
}
```

Read about [Codeigniter Active Record](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html)

Comment: you just know, I use the sql server database, and I use 2 tables (master - details).

so I have to save the master first, so I can save the details.
data ['Detail'] from the dynamic table <table> </ table>

What is the solution? thank you

Comment: That looks like a different question, and since you're not providing enough info I don't know. Did you read "how to ask" guide as AnthonyB suggested?